# Edit files in mounted Docker Volume

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I use the `jupyter/scipy-notebook` Docker to work with some existing scripts and files.
The command I use to start is:

```
docker run -p 10000:8888 -v /home/qohelet/persistent/MoP/pyversioning:/home/jovyan/pyversioning --name scipynotebook jupyter/scipy-notebook:2023-02-28
```

However when I try to create a new file I get a `permission denied`. It's also not possible to edit existing files. There is so far no Dockerfile. Is it possible to set the permissions correctly in the docker call?

I tried to set the permissions of the folder to 777, but no changes so far.

Answer (score 0):

The container runs under UID 1000 and that UID probably doesn't have access to your host directory.

You can run the container under your UID and GID by adding `-u $(id -u):$(id -g)` to your command so you get

```
docker run -p 10000:8888 -u $(id -u):$(id -g) -v /home/qohelet/persistent/MoP/pyversioning:/home/jovyan/pyversioning --name scipynotebook jupyter/scipy-notebook:2023-02-28
```

Comment: Very strange. Executing it without `-u $(id -u):$(id -g)` works perfectly fine. However I get a `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/jovyan/.local'` when executed with the additional parameters